# How do I pass a unique value to a function when calling my PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will extract some images from a zipped file and move them to a directory on a computer.

Because the folder name will always be different, I am using param when running the script to pass the username, like so

```
param ($username)
$_extractpath = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\"
$_extractzip = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\jackets.zip"
$_jackets = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\jackets"

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force | powershell -File .\JACKETS_COPY_NEW.ps1 -username chaos
```

I want to put my script in a function and call it with the value in param, but I can't think how to do this without hardcoding the username inside the script when calling the function...

```
ESKJacketsMove "chaos"
```

Is it possible to have it in a function? or should I just stick with param?

I want to be able to just call the script and specify the username and have it do all the work. I don't want to call ESKJacketsMove directly in the powershell command line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wouldn't need the `param` to be `$username` since it is already a built in environment variable.

Comment: Neko - Do you mean $env:USERNAME?

Comment: Yes, the necessity for `param` with `$username` is redundant.

Comment: Neko - Sorry, I should have been clearer. I explained in a comment below why I can't user $env:USERNAME.

Comment: When the script is ran, it needs to be done using an administrator privileges account which runs under the 'Run As Administrator'. When I tried using $env:USERNAME it returns back the administrator account... And in my scenario, I need "C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\Downloads" to reference the logged on user; hence my reason for using param to specify the username.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [about_function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7), you can try :

```
Function ESKJacketsMove 
{
  param ($username)
  $_extractpath = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\"
  $_extractzip = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\jackets.zip"
  $_jackets = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\jackets"

  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force | powershell -File .\JACKETS_COPY_NEW.ps1 - 
  username $username
}
```

or

```
Function ESKJacketsMove ($username)
{
  $_extractpath = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\"
  $_extractzip = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\jackets.zip"
  $_jackets = "C:\Users\$username\Downloads\jackets"

  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force | powershell -File .\JACKETS_COPY_NEW.ps1 - 
  username $username
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Will this still work even if the command to execute the function 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force | powershell -File .\JACKETS_COPY_NEW.ps1 - username $username' is embedded within the function itself? I don't see how this would work. If it does, how would I execute the script from the powershell command line?

Answer (score 0):

Do your paths like this,

```
$path = "C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\Downloads"
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce. I did toy with this, but this wont work for my scenario. When the script is ran, it needs to be done using an administrator privileges account which runs under the 'Run As Administrator'. When I tried using $env:USERNAME it returns back the administrator account... And in my scenario, I need "C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\Downloads" to reference the logged on user; hence my reason for using param to specify the username. Sorry for the confusing explanation!